# Coding a mathematical problem in Scilab or C++

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, computer-science

As mathematicians need every so often to use programming in the process of a mathematical problem solving, may I ask a question regarding coding within this context? If yes, how can I text the code I want to ask about? and what are the appropriate tags for it? If not, why not?

Comment: If it's more likely to get a good answer from coders than from mathematicians, ask it on a coding site, instead.

Comment: Closely related: [Do we actually "welcome Questions about software that mathematicians use"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/do-we-actually-welcome-questions-about-software-that-mathematicians-use)  When writing your own software in a generic programming language, it would be fitting to limit your Math.SE Questions to the issue of algorithms (not asking us to review your code).

Comment: As hardmath mentions, we don't mind any code, so long as the question is mathematical.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is an entire Stack Exchange site dedicated to these topics: [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Their [help center](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't mention Scilab in their list of *software packages or languages used broadly in computational science*, but it seems to fit the bill.