# Can I ask Geogebra questions on this site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

There are certain questions, answer of which require a graph, diagram or animation of locus or more precisely something related to Geogebra.

So, is asking input command of how to make any animation for e.g. "*How to make cardioid animation in Geogebra*" considered on-topic?

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) has a [Geogebra tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geogebra) but I noticed that the question there are simply ignored (this is not the only reason). I thought that Geogebra has wide use in Math SE, too, so why not ask question here itself. It may also help other users to get familiar with Geogebra interface which in turn would enhance the quality of answer by using it.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/do-we-actually-welcome-questions-about-software-that-mathematicians-use

Comment: Note that GeoGebra has a fairly mature forum for [help and support](https://help.geogebra.org/), and that many "how do I..." questions may already have been asked and answered there.  Searches on "animation" and "cardioid" (separately) there returned multiple results, not all in English.

Comment: @hardmath's link now forwards to reddit, which is clearly actively being used, but is significantly less usable as a Q&A site than stackexchange sites are. (For example, there is no way to comment on an old question if the situation has changed, I don't think there's a notion of "accepted" answer, etc.) So I do think the general question of "Which stackexchange site is best for asking Geogebra questions" is still/again a valid one, and I would be curious about peoples' answers to that.

Comment: Actually, the geogebra tag on Stack Overflow now seems mildly active, certainly better than "all questions are ignored", so I just asked there.