# My question was closed, but there was no explanation so I cannot improve it.

Tags: support, closed-questions

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Remove objects in GeoGebra and keep dependent object.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198243/remove-objects-in-geogebra-and-keep-dependent-object)

I didn't know if asking about GeoGebra was okay here, so I first did a search to see if others had wrote any questions about it. I got 1437 hits, which I interpreted as though it is on topic.

After a few days my question was closed and it said

"This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center.
...
(Private feedback for you)".

I then looked in the help center where i found this at the top:

"... We welcome questions about:...Software that mathematicians use..."

Now I am puzzled. There were no private feedback. It only said "(Private feedback for you)".

What is wrong with the question?

Comment: Generally questions about mathematics software are on topic when the question is primarily mathematical.  When they're about how the software functions then that's for a different forum -- maybe StackOverflow or maybe a help site for the specific software.  Your question does not appear to be about maths or how to do something mathematical with the software, but how to perform certain actions in the software -- which are better suited to a GeoGebra help forum

Comment: See for example the discussion here: [Do we actually "welcome questions about: • Software that mathematicians use"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9073/10513)

Comment: @postmortes Yeah, it seems that I overestimated the usefulness of SE a bit. I thought I had finally found an alternative to registering on dozens of forums. If you can change this to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Mathphyte no need -- hardmath below has pretty much provided the answer for you, and they've also kindly commented on the original question as well.  I think they deserve it :)

Comment: @postmortes Yeah, I saw that. Your answer was first and I also found it a better one, so I thought I'd at least give you the opportunity first =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The text you quoted, " ... (Private feedback for you)", refers to a part of the Closed Question banner that is only visible to you and to users who have enough reputation to vote to reopen it.

I have now left you [a Comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198243/remove-objects-in-geogebra-and-keep-dependent-object#comment8731564_4198243), although I was not one of those who voted to close it, explaining why your Question is not suited to Math.SE.  The fact that there *exist* many Questions here mentioning or involving GeoGebra does not imply that *every* Question that mentions or involves GeoGebra will be on-topic.  But you were right to search previous Questions for the possibility that what you wanted to know has already been provided.