# Why did my question about Lie algebra software get closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question about mathematics software [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4625481/cartan-matrix-software), and the question was closed as "this question is not about mathematics." But there are numerous questions on this site asking for mathematics software [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51284/topology-software), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142276/graphic-software), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/educational-math-software). What am I missing?

Comment: Those examples are from a decade ago. The site grew, evolved, changed. Just like any other society, some things that were acceptable "back in the day" are no longer acceptable now.

Comment: OK, thank you. I understand.

Comment: A related discussion - but it is general, not about one one particular question: [Do we actually "welcome questions about: • Software that mathematicians use"?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9073) (Moreover it is from 2013 - as mentioned in Asaf Karagila's comment, the stance of the community on various things can evolve an change in various ways.)

Comment: I understand.  I have a follow-up question.  Now, with helps from a person who commented on that question, I have an idea of how to tackle the original question. So should I write an answer myself to my own question? I am asking as it's, as of now a closed question.